# Importing data hosted in ArcGIS into QGIS

Tags: qgis, lidar, import

I am trying to load the data from this site: https://catalogue.data.govt.nz/dataset/lidar-2012-2013-contours-coromandel1 into QGIS, but despite all the options, I can't seem to get any to work.

I tried downloading PHP/CSV etc. but it just results in filename.csv.json and it's 234kb or similar. I tried connecting using a link via add 'ArcGIS REST Server', but that doesn't give me anything either.

So, how can I bring this data into QGIS?

Comment: It looks broken to me - try going to the source at https://data-waikatolass.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/b3e4753e74eb474baa7ea963d78b0e3d_0/explore

Comment: Yeah, I was using that too.. couldn't find any way to get it out (that worked) .. I then tried various things (opening in arc GIS and attempting to export: FAIL, querying the online resource and exporting a JSON:FAIL and several others), I contacted the regional council directly and got access via their Sharepoint drive to the data